# actionbar tabs style in android 3.0 in android

Tags: android

Here is my code to set actionbar tabs style

```
 <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- below attributes have no effect -->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
</style>
```

[Following this developers page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

getting this error in above code

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be this:

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- below attributes have no effect -->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
</style>
```